# vaadin UI development using UIDL & JSON

Tags: json, vaadin, uidl

Could anyone please post an example on how to create the components, windows, forms using UIDL and JSON in vaadin framework.

Lets say I am given `[{"name":"button","caption":"MyBotton"}]`. This example will create a button.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you should not have to bother about the details in the JSON sent by the framework. Book of Vaadin has a short [chapter about the JSON used](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/uidl.json.html). If you really have a need to study the generated JSON (I can't think of a situation when, though), I would assume the easiest way to check is to generate some basic Vaadin apps containing the details you're interested in and the use e.g. Firebug to capture and check the JSON traffic in the HTTP responses. Don't think the details are documented anywhere, you have to check the implementation code or the messages if you want to know details for specific components.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - you can not do that.
Long answer - you should not do that.